# Tool tip inside table data with angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a tool tip for collapse and expand written in angular js .When my chevron down , I need to give click to collapse, when it is on right side we need to collapse.

How to handle it in the code given below.

```
<td>
    <i class="pull-right glyphicon" 
        data-toggle="tooltip" 
        title="Click to Collapse" 
        data-placement="top" 
        ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': !isCollapsed[$index], 'glyphicon-chevron-right': isCollapsed[$index]} "> 
    </i>
</td>
```